# Is there any text data inside jpeg file?

Tags: camera, jpeg, barcode

Is there any text data being stored in a jpeg file or is it only colours and intensity/brightness?

Suppose we have a barcode and say we click a jpeg picture of the barcode. Is it possible to decode that jpeg picture to get the barcode type/data?

Admins, please add the right tags.

Answer (score 0):

1. There are various ways to store textual data inside a JPEG file. This is typically used for things like copyrights, photographer names, captions, subject keywords etc. "JPEG metadata" is probably the phrase to search for.
2. Given a JPEG image of a barcode, it is certainly possible to decode the barcode using a barcode decoder, and...
3. ...if you want to, store that barcode in some suitable metadata location. However, ...
4. ...you can not, in general, assume that this has already been done for some image which happens to contain a barcode.

Comment: Palsson, Thanks for your reply. I understand your 1st and 2nd point but did not understand 3rd and 4th point. Another discussion could be : Do you know any software/api which can help me to decode the jpeg image of the barcode?

Comment: I was unsure about what, if anything, your first paragraph had to to with the second one. If they are completely separate questions, you should split them into two posts. Unfortunately, I don't know any barcode decoders (I do know that they exist; I used to use one at work ages ago). I also think requests for libraries are generally considered [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (item 4).

Comment: I see. Thanks for educating me about dual posts on different questions and I see your point about the libraries.